# how to disable font scaling in Picker

Tags: react-native

I am using a Picker from react-native-picker/picker and I want to disable font scaling on Picker, I am not able to do that as I can't see any props in Picker from which we can disable font scaling, please let me know is there any other way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

you can disable for all app

```
if (Text.defaultProps == null) {
  Text.defaultProps = {};
}
Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false;
```

Comment: I did this but doesn’t work for <Picker>, it only works for <Text>

Comment: yeah It seems picker is not using Text of react native

Comment: @Pooja It's using react-native-web for Picker Item but no idea how to fix